# How can I redirect ctrl+p event to ctrl+shift+p event in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to print in Chrome browser, it shows up the print preview panel to user.

I want to open the system print dialog in chrome instead of the print preview panel.

Is this possible with JavaScript?

Actually I want to override `CTRL+P` with `CTRL+SHIFT+P` in JavaScript.
Some code example will be very much appreciated.

Comment: While it's possible in some cases, don't do that. I'd prefer leave site which wants to decide for me what I should do

Answer (score 4):

This answer is really simple:

**1.You can't**

Print dialogs are not scriptable using JavaScript. They're proprietary parts of browsers themselves.

**2. And absolutely don't think about doing this!**

- It is not your choice, its not your client.
- It has nothing to do with your website.

*Let users choose for themself*

They will press `ctrl+shift+P`  when they want to use system print dialog.

People can disable chrome print view by typing `about:flags` into the address bar and disable Print Preview.

Comment: Actually I have a custom print button which is used to print the page in browser.  Can I fire CTRL+SHIFT+P in Chrome to skip the print preview panel and show directly the system print dialog.

Comment: No you can't, if you want to disable it in your own browser use the `about:flags`

Comment: Some good answers aren't satisfying aren't they ;)  Good luck though.

Comment: probably look at here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188749/printing-page-as-popup-window-is-not-working-on-chrome-working-on-mozilla-and-ie/33192152#33192152
it won't replace control command but does printing stuff.