# printing page as popup window is not working on chrome working on mozilla and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am trying to print a page as popup window. For Mozilla and IE its working but on chrome a popup window appears but it gives "print preview failed".

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bP9l1c0A372JYd9P6BDt?p=preview)

And portion of javascript is -

```
function PrintElem(elem) {
    console.log($(elem).html())

     Popup($( elem).html());
}

function Popup(data)
{
    var printContent = data;
    var disp_setting="toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=no,width=600, height=800"
    var myWindow = window.open("","",disp_setting);
    myWindow.document.write(printContent);

    myWindow.document.close();
    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.print();
    myWindow.close();
    return true;
}
```

Not sure why Chrome is not happy with my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JQuery, you can use `$(document).ready(function () {});`. Have a look at this here:

```
$(function () {
  window.print();
  window.close();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `setTimeout` of `500` milliseconds worked:

```
function Popup(data)
{
  var printContent = data;
  var disp_setting="toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=no,width=600, height=800";
  var myWindow = window.open("","",disp_setting);
  myWindow.document.open();
  myWindow.document.write(printContent);
  myWindow.document.close();
  myWindow.focus();
  setTimeout(function () {
    myWindow.print();
    myWindow.close();
  }, 500);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: @A.Wolff Did you check in Chrome? It shows Print Preview Failed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. for me delay for 1000 worked. seems to me hack though :(

Comment: @VennilaSundarRajan ya but i just tested for a simple div and works. Now i see issue in OP plunker

Comment: @MohdAdnan _"for me delay for 1000 worked. seems to me hack though :( "_ Tried viewing Network tab , Timeline at `console` while loading page ? Several external files appear to be loaded when when page loads . Perhaps   depends on network speed , bandwidth if all external pages loaded when `print` called ?

Comment: That would be like a loading window before the actual print takes place. Well, yes, I agree that it is a hack!

Comment: css and jquery file. My browser says 81ms which is not too much. may be several files are by plunker.

Comment: @MohdAdnan You should use instead `myWindow.onload = function(){
   this.print();
    this.close();
}` not some random timeout delay

Comment: This is indeed an answer. Pl add answer i would accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks A.Wolff for your answer and VennilaSundarRajan for providing insight about issue -
I am posting here on this behalf.
The real problem was time rendering time by page.
use this-

```
myWindow.onload = function(){ this.print(); this.close(); }
```